# Getting the value of a key in an AttributeCollection using LINQ

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-2011, linqpad

I'm testing this out in LINQPad with the CRM plugin.

[image]

What should my query be so that it would return the value of "address1_addressid"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be something like this

```
from c in ContactSet
where ...
select new {
  address1_addressid = c.Attributes.Contains("address1_addressid") ? 
                       c.Attributes["address1_addressid"] : ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

or simply

```
from c in ContactSet
where c.FirstName.Equals("SomeFirstName")
select c.Address1_AddressId
```

Comment: I tested it in my environment and it works...but, use what works for you